# Autoclicker starts but doesn't pause unless it's killed

Tags: python, while-loop, python-keyboard

I'm new to python and I'm working on a small autoclicker that you can turn on & off using the letter 's', however when I press it the autoclicker starts but I can't turn it off unless I use the letter 'k' which is used to stop the program completely, this is what my code looks like:

```
from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button
import keyboard as kb
import time
import multiprocessing

def click():
    
    isToggled = False
    mouse = Controller()

    while True:
        if isToggled:
            mouse.click(Button.left)
            time.sleep(0.01)
        
        if kb.is_pressed('s'):
            if isToggled:
                isToggled = False
            else:
                isToggled = True

        elif kb.is_pressed('k'):
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=click)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because as long as `s` is held down, `kb.is_pressed('s')` will evaluate to `True`. So `isToggled` will rapidly toggle between `True` and `False` until you release the key, and it's anyone's guess what value it will be.

One way you could solve this is to basically lock `isToggled` from being set more than once until `s` is released. Something like this:

```
key_locked = False 
while True:
    ...
    if kb.is_pressed('s'):
        if key_locked:
            continue
        
        key_locked = True
        if isToggled:
            isToggled = False
        else:
            isToggled = True
    else:
        key_pressed = False

    if kb.is_pressed('k'):
        break
```

Comment: It has the same result, I can turn it on with the letter 's' but I can't turn it off with that same letter.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `kb.is_pressed('s')` function returns true while the key is being held, so every time the while loop runs `isToggled` is geting flipped and because if `isToggled` is true there is a sleep, it is more likely that when you release the key, you end up with this value.

You can fix that by adding another variable that stores if the key was pressed in the last iteration and only flip the `isToggled` if it was not. Also as a side note, the fliping of the `isToggled` variable can be simplified a bit. The updated code could look like this:

```
from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button
import keyboard as kb
import time
import multiprocessing


def click():
    isToggled = False
    wasPressed = False
    mouse = Controller()

    while True:
        if isToggled:
            mouse.click(Button.left)
            time.sleep(0.01)

        if kb.is_pressed('s'):
            if not wasPressed:
                isToggled = not isToggled

        elif kb.is_pressed('k'):
            break

        wasPressed = kb.is_pressed('s')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=click)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```